# Can't find document root

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, deployment, directory-structure, document-root

I have a web application (Tomcat, Java, Netbeans). 
I am not able to locate my document root.
my catalina_home is "c:\tomcat" but when I look in "c\tomcat\webapps" I don't see any of my web applications (ie: context paths). I only see 4 folders: "docs, examples, host-manager, manager."

The reason I would like to know is because I recently changed a context path from "applicationName" to "/" and then noticed that tomcat's default favicon is missing.
Now, I would like to reinsert tomcat's favicon into the document root but can't find it. (Obviously tomcat's favicon is not so important to me but I would like to be able to do it with mine when the time comes and also I would like to have a better understanding of the file structure).

Everything else works: I can deploy all my web applications and run them.

Comment: You might have 2 Tomcat installations.

Comment: Is that the only option? (ie: If my program is running then the application context path must be in the c:\tomcat\webapps file?)

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for another way that I can place the favicon in the document root (eg: via netbeans) so that then maybe I can work backwards and do a search for the favicon to see where it is located?

Comment: Regarding 2 installations: If I undeploy "applicationName" and then redeploy it and then go to c:\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost I see a newly created XML document, meaning that the tomcat folder that I am in is the one being used.

Comment: Have a look at Netbeans settings: TopMenu -> "Tools" -> "Servers".

Comment: Yes, like I said, the Catalina_Home is set to c:\tomcat...which is where I'm looking. Or should I be looking for some other information on "Tools"-->"Servers"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to view the document root you need to place the .war file of your web application in the c:/tomcat/webapps folder. Tomcat automatically "explodes" the WAR file.

As far as I can tell, placing the favicon in the document root does not display it globally but rather placing it in the c:/tomcat folder does.

Answer (score 0):

Please search for your application name in context.xml or server.xml inside the conf directory. (Or any other Xml)

Location of the modules might be hiding there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, the context.xml file states the path as path="/applicationName". But this name is not displayed in the tomcat/webapps folder.